# How to concatenate strings in phalcon php phql?

Tags: php, phalcon

I have the following Phql query:

```
$persons = Person::query()
        ->columns([
            'id' => 'id',
            'name' => 'first_name || last_name'
        ])
        ->where("first_name LIKE :searchQuery:")
        ->orWhere("last_name LIKE :searchQuery:")
        ->bind(['searchQuery' => $searchQuery . '%'])
        ->execute();
```

The database used is an **sqlite** database.

The query works fine until I include the concatenation operator of **sqlite** `||`

The exception thrown is:

> Scanner: Unknown opcode 402

I have tried `CONCAT(first_name, last_name)`, but it throws the exception:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such function: CONCAT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also much better is to use dialect extension:

```
namespace App/Dialect;

class Sqlite extends \Phalcon\Db\Dialect\Sqlite
{
    /**
     * Sqlite constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->registerCustomFunctions();
    }

    /**
     * Register Custom dialect functions
     */
    public function registerCustomFunctions()
    {
        $customFunctions = [
            'CONCAT_WS'  => 'ConcatWs',
        ];
        foreach ($customFunctions as $key => $value) {
            $className = 'App\\Dialect\\Extensions\\'.$value;
            $object = new $className;
            $this->registerCustomFunction($key, $object->getFunction());
        }
    }
}

namespace App/Dialect/Extensions;

class ConcatWs
{
    public function getFunction()
    {
        return function (Dialect $dialect, $expression) {
            $sql = '';


            $count = count($expression['arguments']);

            if (true !== $count >= 2) {
                throw new Exception('CONCAT_WS requires 2 or more parameters');
            }

            if (2 === $count) {
                return $this->getSqlExpression($expression['arguments'][1]);
            }

            $separator = array_shift($expression['arguments']);

            --$count;
            foreach ($expression['arguments'] as $argument) {
                $sql .= $this->getSqlExpression($argument);
                if (0 !== --$count) {
                    $sql .= ' || '.$this->getSqlExpression($separator).' || ';
                }
            }

            return $sql;
        };
    }
}
```

And then in your db service:

```
use App/Dialect/Sqlite as SqliteDialect;

$di->set('db', function() {
    return new Sqlite([
        // other options, like password etc
        'dialectClass' => SqliteDialect::class
    ]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Sadly this is not supported for sqllite, but you can extend the class and add support for MySQL concat function. Here is a working solution: https://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/15233/concatenate-columns-using-sqlite

**MySQL solution:**

```
->columns([
    'id',
    'CONCAT_WS("@", id, created_at) AS concatenatedValue',
])
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [concatenatedValue] => 1@2017-04-04 12:08:52
```

Comment: Is this for sqlite? It did not work with exception: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such function: CONCAT_WS

Comment: Ohhh, really sorry, missed the sqlite part. This is mysql. Can you try perhaps `(first_name || last_name) AS con...` ? Ill check for sqlite solution right now :)

Comment: Thanks. Tried it with parenthesis as you suggested. Still says `Scanner: Unknown opcode 402`

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Found a solution for sqllite, you can check the link above.